# executing a jar file says JarRsrcLoader not found

Tags: eclipse, jar

When I try to execute a jar file, I get an error saying "Could not find the main class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader. Program will exit." Is this some eclipse plugin that I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to verify if the class in question is indeed inside the jar. Alternatively you can run the jar file inside Explorer or command line (i.e. using java directly).